# DataGridView show/hide cell content while manual resizing

Tags: c#, datagridview

This is my first question here but I'm regular visitor, I've been searching workaround for this for over a week now, I suspect it is something easy but...

**How to force the DataGridView to show cell content while manual resizing columns?**

When you resize a column you see cells values after you release the mouse button. I want it to be shown/hidden exactly while resizing. I was trying to make it with **MouseDown**. If there's another easier way let me know. If no I'll still need some help making it. Thanks.

Comment: I think that's one of the Windows performance options https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+show+content+while+dragging ?

Comment: Nope, the problem is in C# code not in the visual effects on the OS.